# Using foreman with more than one .env file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

With foreman, I'm trying to start my rails app using two .env files.

One is the regular .env file, but then a second one has extra variables to load.  I'm trying to use the method mentioned in this guide to keep config variables out of code: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Here is my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT --env $RACK_ENV,var.env
```

My problem is that foreman doesn't seem to want to take the two arguments for --env, even though the docs say that it should be possible:

> -e, --env
>
> Specify an alternate environment file. You can specify more than one file by using: --env file1,file2.

When I try to run it with "foreman start," I get the error:

```
06:22:46 web.1  | You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your development,var.env environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/development,var.env.rb
```

It just doesn't seem to want to split "development,var.env" and process them separately.  When I looked at the foreman code, it looks like it should just do a simple split on the comma, so I can't tell if I'm doing something wrong or it's a bug.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I didn't use that feature yet but from the [docs](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/#RUNNING) I would say your are trying to specify the command line parameter in the wrong place. Instead of adding it to the process in the `Procfile` you should add it to the `foreman` command itself:

```
foreman start --env .env,.env.local
```

That way the environment is set for all processes started by foreman.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  I just had the two different --env confused.  Doing `foreman start --env first.env,second.env`  works like it should